# Find the angles of the triangle if $∠BAC = 60°$ and $AB + BA' = AB' + BB'$.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $AA′$ and $BB′$ be the bisectors of the angles $∠BAC$ and $∠ABC$ of the triangle $ABC$. Find the angles of the triangle if $∠BAC = 60°$ and $AB + BA' = AB' + BB'$.

Hi, can anybody solve this problem for me?

Thanks

Comment: @Arthur:  I double checked it. It is correct. It shouldn't be too much complicated because it is a challenging problem from high school materials.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is $\angle ABC=80°$ (see diagram below). In that case $BB'C$ is an isosceles triangle and $BB'=B'C$. In addition, if $C'$ is the point on $AC$ such that $\angle CA'C'=40°$, then triangles $ABC$ and $AA'C'$ are congruent, while $A'C'C$ is isosceles. We have then:
$$
AB'+BB'=AB'+B'C=AC
$$
and
$$
AB+BA'=AC'+A'C'=AC'+C'C=AC.
$$
It follows that this triangle satisfies the given property and is indeed a solution.

I proved that no other solutions exist, but through a complicated trig equation, which cannot be solved in a simple way. I'm sure that some more simple and elegant proof can be found.

[image]

Comment: How did you assume at the beginning that ABC is 80 degree?

Comment: Making a sketch with GeoGebra.

Comment: But I think that we cannot find it by sketching. There should be an algebraic solution.

Comment: @NarimanZendehrooh: While the supposition that $\angle ABC = 80^\circ$ was *observed* in a sketch, Aretino *did* show that the solution was valid. ("Guess and check" is a *perfectly reasonable* approach to problem-solving!) The only question is whether more solutions exist. As Aretino suggests ---and my solution shows--- the trigonometry behind that determination is rather complicated; if the problem statement leads one to believe that the solution is unique, then it's not completely unreasonable to leave the latter part fo the argument out unless/until someone specifically requested it.

Answer (score 2):

To reduce notational clutter, define $\alpha := A/2$, $\beta := B/2$, $c := |\overline{AB}|$, $e := |\overline{BB^\prime}|$, $p := |\overline{A^\prime B}|$, $q := |\overline{AB^\prime}|$. We won't yet impose the condition $A = 60^\circ$.

[image]

By the Law of Sines, we have
$$
\frac{e}{\sin 2\alpha} = \frac{c}{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)} \qquad
\frac{p}{\sin\alpha} = \frac{c}{\sin(\alpha+2\beta)} \qquad
\frac{q}{\sin\beta} = \frac{c}{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)} \tag{1}$$

The condition equating sums of lengths says
$$c\;\frac{\sin\alpha + \sin(\alpha+2\beta)}{\sin(\alpha+2\beta)} = c+p = e+q = c\;\frac{\sin 2\alpha + \sin \beta}{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)} \tag{2}$$

Thus,

$$\left(\;\sin\alpha + \sin(\alpha+2\beta)\;\right) \sin(2\alpha+\beta) = \left(\;\sin 2\alpha + \sin\beta\;\right)\sin(\alpha+2\beta) \tag{3}$$

In the absence of particularly-keen insight, there really isn't much to do but expand the trig expressions and hope for simplification. These days, this is the kind of thing I leave to a computer algebra system like *Mathematica*. As it turns out, we get a very nice simplification:

> $$4\;\sin\alpha\;\sin\left(\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\beta\right)\;\left( \cos\beta - \frac{1}{2} \right)\;\cos\left(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\beta\right) = 0 \tag{4}$$

Our options are these:

$$\begin{align}
\sin\alpha= 0: &\quad\to\quad \alpha = 0^\circ \quad\text{or}\quad \alpha = 180^\circ \quad\to\quad\text{degenerate triangle} \tag{5a}\\
\sin\left(\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\beta\right) = 0: &\quad\to\quad
\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\beta = 180^\circ \quad\to\quad\text{impossible: $\alpha+\beta < 90^\circ$} \tag{5b} \\
\cos\beta = \frac{1}{2}: &\quad\to\quad \beta = 60^\circ \quad\to\quad B = 120^\circ \tag{5c} \\
\cos\left(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\beta\right) = 0: &\quad\to\quad
\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\beta = 90^\circ \quad\to\quad B = 120^\circ - \frac{2}{3}A\tag{5d}
\end{align}$$

Of the two viable solutions, we dismiss $B = 120^\circ$ *only* because the previously-ignored condition $A = 60^\circ$ would imply a degenerate triangle. This leaves only (5d), which, with the ignored condition, gives

> $$B = 80^\circ \qquad C = 40^\circ \tag{6}$$

Done. $\square$

---

That the brute-force expansion of (3) is so very messy, yet simplifies so very well to (4), suggests that there may be something very interesting going on here. Of course, invoking the condition $\alpha = 30^\circ$ at that stage would have reduced the symbolic complexity in the expansion, but I don't think the problem gets appreciably *easier* from an algebraic standpoint; indeed, as it probably would have been *more difficult* to glean options (5b) and (5d) from a mess of $1/2$s and $\sqrt{3}/2$s, I'm led to believe that the condition must be exploitable *geometrically*. Moreover, with $B$ being related to *two-thirds* of $A$, perhaps some sneaky trisection is at work in the general case. For the moment, whatever clever approach these facts may be hinting-at has escaped me.

Comment: Nice solution. What kind of *Mathematica* statement did you use to get that awesome simplification?

Comment: @Aretino: `TrigFactor[(Sin[a]+Sin[a+2b])Sin[2a+b]-(Sin[2a]+Sin[b])Sin[a+2b]]`